# Jenkins git plugin and branches

Tags: git, plugins, branch, jenkins

I have a job set up in Jenkins to build all my feature branches (feature/**). It is working nicely with the Build Name Setter plugin to identify different builds with Jenkins branch setter name plugin.

My question is, if there are changes to more than one branch at the same time, will it queue the same job multiple times? Or it will just build first branch (or last branch) that it finds, and next branch will be picked up during next poll and so on? Or it will just build a branch that was changed last and ignore all other branches? I can’t figure this out, and didn’t find it documented clearly.

Comment: What is that "build name plugin"? Doesn't its documentation answer your question already?

Comment: I don't know anything about it, but from googling, I expect it's [this Jenkins plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Name+Setter+Plugin). It looks like all it does is rename builds, so the question would be how Jenkins triggers builds, and likely doesn't have anything to do with the plugin.

Comment: Right, how Jenkins 'git-plugin' works. 'Build name setter plugin' just names the builds per branch, so I know what branch it is building.

Comment: I've edited your question to include sufficient information. (You'll get more helpful answers if you provide it to begin with - you never mentioned Jenkins.) From what I understand, the branch name plugin is probably irrelevant. As for the answer, if Jenkins is at all sane, then when it sees multiple things that should be built, it'll build all of them (maybe in a queue). Can't you just try it?

Comment: Thanks, I was expecting what you wrote, however when I tried, it built only last changed branch. Thought this is weird, so trying to get confirmation.. Thanks again

Comment: Ah, I see. You can also edit your own questions to add more information like that into them. You might be out of luck though; I found this: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-11337 The plugin seems to have a *lot* of open, major issues.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can try the *job-per-branch* approach. It comes with its own set of problems and depending on the number of branches you're dealing with, you might need tools to help you manage the process:

- [jenkins-build-per-branch](http://entagen.github.com/jenkins-build-per-branch/)
- [jenkins-autojobs](http://packages.python.org/jenkins-autojobs/)

Comment: This doesn't answer the original question. The alternatives are nice information, but not what was asked. In my case (and perhaps the OP's as well), I specifically do not want _job-per-branch_ because the proliferation of jobs adds confusion (even with automation) and my team shares Jenkins with other teams in a large company.

Answer (score 1):

This has been a known issue with the Jenkins Git Plugin for some time now. It will only build master, even on changes to specific branches.

An older version used to work correctly, so you may be able to work around this if you install a version prior to 1.1.xxx (1.359 is the last known working version).

As mentioned earlier by Jefromi, you can view the details here: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-11337, and up vote the issue if desired.